# Fragment is not getting replace

Tags: java, android, fragment

Hi I'm making an app where I'm using bottom navigation to navigate through the fragments but my problem is when I click the app is loaded fragments are not visible in frame layout and even when I click bottom navigation it is just showing blank page below is my code for the main activity I searched for this problem on google but looks like I'm the only one having this problem

I have the main activity as **dashboard** in which I want to implement bottom navigation everything seems perfect still fragments are not showing

dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">


<!--    Framelayout: show fragment-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

<!--    Bottom nav : show menu-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Dashboard.java

```
package com.example.trella;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //firebase  auth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        
        //Action bar its title
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Profile");

        //init
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        BottomNavigationView bnv= findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bnv.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

    }

    private  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_profile:
                            selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_users:
                            selectedFragment = new UsersFragment();
                            break;

                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

    private void  checkUserStatus(){
        //get current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user !=null){
            //user is signed in stays here


        }
        else {
            //user is not signed in , login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        //check user status
        checkUserStatus();

        super.onStart();
    }

    //inflate options menu


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //inflating menu
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //handle menu click event

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        //get item id
        int id =   item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_logout){
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            checkUserStatus();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Although the set title is working
`actionBar.setTitle("Home");`

Comment: In Your layout id is `R.id.content` while you are using `R.id.fragment_container` as a container .

Comment: You should use Navigation Component for your BottomNavigationView. Refer to this tutorial - https://youtu.be/Chso6xrJ6aU

Answer (score 0):

Update below line in your code, the id should be content instead of fragment_container.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,new HomeFragment()).commit();
```